# How do I hide the default logo space in Navigation Bar?

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

Currently my navigation drawer is showing a default space before 'Settings and Privacy' item. I want to remove this space and make the text aligned to left.

[image]

How can I do this?

Here's my XML code:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_bookmarks"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_bookmarks_24"
        android:title="Bookmarks"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_topics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_topic_24"
        android:title="Topics"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_lists"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_featured_play_list_24"
        android:title="Lists"
        />
</group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:title="Settings and privacy"
            android:icon="@null"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_help"
            android:title="Help Centre"
            android:icon="@null"
            />
    </group>
```

Comment: what did you try till now to hide the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 groups of item in your menu like this and divide them to icon and non icon

```
<group
android:id="@+id/menu_top"
<item>
</item>
<item>
</item>
</group>
<group
android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
<item>
android:icon="@null"
</item>
<item>
android:icon="@null"
</item>
</group>
```

This should remove the space automatically since you have two groups of items

if that doesn't work use

```
int positionOfMenuItem =3; //the position of item you need to the left

MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);

SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);

s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_LEFT), 0, s.length(), 0);

item.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: is it giving the same behavior as before ?.just with a seperator?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the @null with this combination, I hope this helps and solves your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="Primary">

            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:title="@string/menu_home" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
            </menu>

        </item>

        <item android:title="Secondary">
            <menu android:title="Second Category">
                <group
                    android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
                    android:checkableBehavior="single">
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                        android:icon="@null"
                        android:title="Settings and Privacy" />
                </group>

            </menu>

        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: this is working but it is leaving space for the section title.

Comment: @Haneen According to material design if you want to show only labels for the items in navigation drawer then you need to remove icons from all the items and only use labels, https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#anatomy

Or if you are ok to use some custom layout like introducing Recyclerview then you can achieve both what you want. For custom navigation drawer you can refer this link [link](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-a-custom-navigation-drawer-in-android-using-kotlin/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@null` value for the drawable icon.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings_and_privacy"
    android:icon="@null"
    android:title="@string/settings_and_privacy" />
```

Comment: After the Edit, I see that you are already using null. I will check and get back in some time.

Comment: Thanks you for the contribution @Mohit Ajwani!